How to plot asteroid position according to uncertainties on osculating orbital elements?
A few years ago I made a program to compute asteroids positions and focus on close approaches (under 10 000 km). On average there is one every day. Leftmost numbers represent MJD date and 'ds' is distance in 1000 km between asteroids.

Now it would be interesting to know the probability that the asteroids are actually at the predicted positions.
Thanks to JPL Small-Bodies Database we know the uncertainties of all osculating orbital elements.
Given those uncertainties, how can we calculate the radius of a blurred sphere representing an asteroid's position with a given precision, let say 78% which correspond to JPL's published uncertainties of one-Sigma?
Following Greg Miller's suggestion I calculated position varying orbital data within 6 embedded loop with zero, plus and minus uncertainty for each of the 6 osculating elements.
This give 3^6 or 729 positions. But the resulting points cloud seems quite unrealistic, not close to a sphere but an elongate cigar! Like this picture of 2 asteroid in close approach.

What am I doing wrong?

Choose random numbers +/- the uncertainty and use it to compute the position.  Repeat a bunch of times to create a point cloud.

Great solution! Sure must work. But does an analytic solution exist?

This is an interesting question, but I think there is a problem here, having to do with correlations between parameters and how those uncertainties are defined and calculated.

But I have a question - what does your program actually DO? For example, do you obtain the osculating parameters for the specific time that you calculate the position, or do you use osculating parameters from some other time, and then propagate a Keplerian orbit based on those parameters forwards or backwards in time to calculate closest approach. I think tyou need to make that clear before a correct, useful answer providing an "analytical solution" can be provided. Thanks!

Actually, I do not propagate Keplerian orbit. I used the periodically published elements (last epoch is MJD 60600) calculate position for main belt asteroid keeping track of candidates within 10 000 km then check against JPL Horizon system for more accuracy.

I would not expect the point cloud to resemble a circle, the ellipses you got seem plausible.  The errors will generally not be the same in all dimensions, which gives the elliptical shape.

Ok, Greg, I realize that's correct.
Now there is the correlations between parameters like uhoh pointed out that might distort the cloud shape. I am using the semi-major axis to compute the period of rotation and determine mean anomaly. So using uncertainties of axis AND anomaly might be overdoing thing.

To compute asteroid's position you can use NASA  Small-Body Database Lookup  web page for orbital data, ephemeris and uncertainties.
To check the calculated positions you can use  JPL's Horizon system  for more options.
example: 2000 FX40(id 20050835) or 2014 HO64 (id 54099790)
Note that the first is a numbered asteroid with more precise orbital data (12 km) than the second (2040 km)
Image of their orbits and point clouds looking from
Z axis

This approach at 300 km will happen 2024-09-11 04:55 UTC.
Check viewing conditions at specific sites and time with Horizon's system.
It would be interesting to have a more precise orbit for (2014 HO64). Many more observations are required.
PS: link for photography of 2000 FX40 & 2014 HO64 approach by Filipp Romanof posting on mpml@groups.io

or this link for further info on the whole thread.
